# Perform various actions on a list

Tags: python, programming-challenge, array, comparative-review

I am solving the following [HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem):

> Consider a list (list = []). You can perform the following commands:
>
> - `insert i e`: Insert integer e at position i.
> - `print`: Print the list.
> - `remove e`: Delete the first occurrence of integer e.
> - `append e`: Insert integer e at the end of the list.
> - `sort`: Sort the list.
> - `pop`: Pop the last element from the list.
> - `reverse`: Reverse the list.
>
> Initialize your list and read in the value of followed by lines of
> commands where each command will be of the types listed above. Iterate
> through each command in order and perform the corresponding operation
> on your list.

My solution was:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    
    my_list = []
    
    commands = dict(
            insert=lambda i,v: my_list.insert(i,v),
            print=lambda: print(my_list),
            remove=lambda e: my_list.remove(e),
            append=lambda v: my_list.append(v),
            sort=lambda: my_list.sort(),
            pop=lambda: my_list.pop(),
            reverse=lambda: my_list.reverse()
        )
    
    for _ in range(N):
        command, *args = input().split()
        commands[command](*list(map(int, args)))
```

I did find another solution (I didn't write it) that seems cleaner than mine:

```
n = input()
l = []
for _ in range(n):
    s = raw_input().split()
    cmd = s[0]
    args = s[1:]
    if cmd !="print":
        cmd += "("+ ",".join(args) +")"
        eval("l."+cmd)
    else:
        print l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Most of your `lambda`s are unnecessary wrappers around perfectly fine functions, so I'd just use the latter instead.
- The `list` in `(*list(map(...)))` is unnecessary, just unpack the iterable that `map` gets you.
- There's nothing else in your code, so importing it doesn't give you anything, so you'd just run the script, so `if __name__ == '__main__':` is rather pointless.
- I'd read the number of commands only when I need it, not early.
- I find `my_list` unnecessarily verbose, a commonly used name is `lst`.
- Indent the `dict` arguments by the standard four spaces instead of eight.
  So, rewritten:

```
lst = []

commands = dict(
    insert=lst.insert,
    print=lambda: print(lst),
    remove=lst.remove,
    append=lst.append,
    sort=lst.sort,
    pop=lst.pop,
    reverse=lst.reverse
)

for _ in range(int(input())):
    command, *args = input().split()
    commands[command](*map(int, args))
```

As shown in some other solutions in the discussion, we can use `getattr` instead of building our own `dict` serving pretty much the same purpose. I didn't see anyone using its default parameter, though, which can neatly cover the `print` command:

```
lst = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    command, *args = input().split()
    getattr(lst, command, lambda: print(lst))(*map(int, args))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About the `if ... __main __` it was just copy paste from hackerrank.